# Converting Outlook SentOn() Long Date/Time to only short date

Tags: powershell, datetime, outlook

When performing the following command on my Outlook email:

```
$EmailDateTime = $mail.SentOn
```

$EmailDateTime equals "Friday, July 15, 2022 6:26:57 PM"

How do I convert this format into MM/DD/YYYY format? For this example, I would like $EmailDateTime to be 7/15/2022. No time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.SentOn` property is a `[DateTime]` type, so if you want that date formatted a specific way for use in a string you can use the `.ToString()` method to format it accordingly.

```
$EmailDateTime = $mail.SentOn.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

That will make it so that `$EmailDateTime` is a string, instead of a datetime, with the format of MM/dd/yyyy.